# sqlite3_prepare_v2 doesn't return sqlite_ok on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying out SQLite in iPhone for the very first time. The error I am facing is that the statement `sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK` in th ecode below is returning false and nothing is displayed.

Below is my code:

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

dbTryAppDelegate *appDelegate = (dbTryAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "select name,id from studtry";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
//below line is never executed and its else part is also not executed.
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            stud *coffeeObj = [[stud alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.studName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

            //coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;

            [appDelegate.studArray addObject:coffeeObj];
          //  [coffeeObj release];
        }
    }
}
else
    sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve it?

Comment: MFDB is much easier then above method please try to implement FMDB

Comment: i ll do that but first let me know what's wrong with this code!

Comment: If you ever get an error, you should `NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));`. That will tell you what the error is. It's silly for us to try to guess what's going on unless you tell us what the error message is.

Comment: i got the error- it was with the database naming. Practice.sql and practice.sql

Answer (score 0):

Check Database Path, Database extension and also same table & fields.

Anyways,

Use This instead of using directly const string::

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name,id from studtry"];

const char *sql = [sqlStr UTF8String];
```

After while loop finalize statement,

```
sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
```

Then, after If condition,

```
 sqlite3_close(database);
```

No need to write in else part.

Hopefully, it'll work for you.
Thanks.

Comment: May be it will not get table 'studtry' as well as field of it. check table name & fields. First check log for query by "NSLog(@" Query -> %@", sqlStr). Then whatever you get, execute it in SQLite & check for result. You can get help from it.

Comment: logged it->output-> select name, id from studtry. Tablename is also correct

Comment: now execute "select name, id from studtry" into SQLiteManager & tell me if you get any records.

Comment: from where did you get this records?

Comment: From SQLite of Project Directory or In Application Document Directory ?

Comment: i am sorry but i am not getting you. I had already inserted sample data in sqlite and i get those data in the sqlite tool of firefox

Comment: See, Go to Library by: Ctrl + Shift + G ==> ~/Library. Then you'll get whole path for your application like :: /Users/c33/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/CA68BEE5-BD44-48BE-8CAC-75F9CEA87616/Documents. In this path, you have sqlite file. check for this tables & 
sql queries

Comment: crtl+shift+G isn't working. I opened library through the finder in MAC. i found the path to be something like:/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/CA.....somevalue/Documents/Practice.sql

Comment: check that Practice.sql file. Check whether Table & fields are created properly or not.

Comment: ah, i got it! the sql file in documents folder was stored as practise.sql, but actually it is Practise.sql...Still the view is not displayed. thanks mate!

Comment: Try this my new answer and tell me if you'll not get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, all thing is abs right but I think you are passing the wrong `DBPath` or maybe `DB` file is not on the right place 
please check this both point and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First delete your application from Application & Simulator Folder.
Then create Database named :: Practise.sqlite3 (Type of SQLite3)

Then write this methods for Copying:

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSError *error;
   dbPath = [self getDBPath];

       BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

   if(!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Practise.sqlite3"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
   if (!success)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
}


- (NSString *) getDBPath {

      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
      NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

      return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Practise.sqlite3"];
}
```

You can copy this whenever you want by,

```
[self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
```

Then, check for your results. Hopefully it'll work.